# Overriding dependency at runtime in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a service called `$doggedHttp`, which exposes the same interface as `$http`.
Now I want to create a `$doggedResource` service which is the angular `$resource` service on top of `$doggedHttp` instead of `$http`. In other word I want to inject `$doggedHttp` as the `$http` service.

Also, in my application I want to be able to create both `$doggedResource` and `$resource`. Thus I cannot simply override `$http` with `$doggedHttp`.

I thought dependency injection should make this scenario easy to solve. Am I wrong ?

Instead I had to go deep into the angular source code to finally came up with a quite ugly  solution :

```
angular.module('doggedResource', ['ngResource', 'doggedHttp'])
  .config(function() {
    var ngResource = angular.module('ngResource'),
        doggedResource = angular.module('doggedResource');

    // replace the placeholder below with the $resource factory from ngResource
    doggedResource._invokeQueue[1][2][1][2] = ngResource._invokeQueue[0][2][1][2];
})
.factory('$doggedResource', ['$doggedHttp', '$parse', null /* this is just a placeholder */]);
```

Is there a better solution ?

---

Remark that we cannot use `$provide.decorator` to replace the injected `$http` service.
To illustrate the problem, here are the relevant parts of [angular-resource.js](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular-resource.js) :

```
angular.module('ngResource', ['ng']).
  factory('$resource', ['$http', '$parse', function($http, $parse) {

    function ResourceFactory(url, paramDefaults, actions) {
    }

    return ResourceFactory;
  }
```

Looking at the code above, the `$provide.decorator` callback will be passed ResourceFactory as an argument. At that time the dependency `$http` has already been resolved. And since ResourceFactory use `$http` inside a closure we cannot change it.

```
.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator( '$resource', [ "$delegate", function( $delegate ) {
    // here $delegate is the ResourceFactory which has 
    // already been linked to `$http` by a closure.
  }
}
```

Comment: So, your 'doggedHttp', it is it's own module? You did angular.module('doggedHttp',[])? You didn't just add a factory to the current module?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you need to do this? If it's for mocking during unit-testing there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: @aaronfrost yes 'doggedHttp' is a module that define '$doggedHttp'

Comment: @ivarni It's not for mocking $http. $doggedHttp is the same as $http but it behaves differenty in case of error. It will automatically retry and store the request in localStorage if there is no internet connection. It will also replay the stored requests once the Internet connection is back. This behavior is desirable only on some resources, not all of them them.

Comment: Without having done anything similar, I think the config function is the right place to do it. Could you decorate the $httpProvider in a way similar to this example with $log? https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/DWOMe6c7L_Q/D1huYc6y2WAJ

Comment: @ivarni unfortunately you cannot use $provide.decorator here. Inside the decorator callback, you get the ResourceFactory which has already been linked to $http via a closure inside the ResourceFactory's Factory. I will edit my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write all the logic that is there in `$doggedHttp` in a decorator for `$http`. Once you decorate `$http`, everything should work fine

**EDIT :** Correction for condition.

```
.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator( '$http', [ "$delegate", function( $delegate ) {
    // here $delegate is the $http function.
    function $doggedHttp(config){
        //write your storage logic here.

        // route all the $http calls through $delegate at the end... 
        return $delegate(config);
    }
    //dont forget to create shortcut method overrides.
    //createShortMethods('get', 'delete', 'head', 'jsonp');
    //createShortMethodsWithData('post', 'put');

    // This is the simplest solution to what you wish to do..
    if( condition ) {
         return $doggedHttp; 
    }
    else { 
         return $delegate;
    }     

    //finally return the $doggedHttp ( and not the $delegate ) 

  }
}
```

Alternately, you can write all your storage logic in a `request interceptor` - You can inject anything and everything in there as well, so storing your calls and re-requesting can also be done at that stage.

Comment: If I do that, any call to the $http service will be intercepted. Which is not what I want. I want to be able to use the base $http and $doggedHttp in the same application.

Comment: Does a simple if condition in the `$delegate` not work for you?