# Restangular - how to cancel/implement my own request

Tags: restangular

I found a few examples of using `fullRequestInterceptor` and `httpConfig.timeout` to allow canceling requests in restangular.

[example 1](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/520) | [example 2](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/589)

this is how I'm adding the interceptor:

```
    app.run(function (Restangular, $q) {
        Restangular.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
```

I managed to abort the request by putting a resolved promise in timeout (results in an error being logged and the request goes out but is canceled), which is not what I want.

What I'm trying to do - I want to make the AJAX request myself with my own requests and pass the result back to whatever component that used Restangular. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking a restangular way to solve it, but I should have been looking for an angular way :)

[Overriding dependency at runtime in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353515/overriding-dependency-at-runtime-in-angularjs)

Looks like you can extend `$http` before it ever gets to Restangular. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like it would fit my needs 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using requestInterceptor a lot, but only to change parameters and headers of my request.

Basically addFullRequestInterceptor is helping you making change on your request before sending it. So why not changing the url you want to call ?

There is the httpConfig object that you can modify and return, and if it's close to the config of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) (and I bet it is) you can change the url and even method, and so change the original request to another one, entirely knew.

After that you don't need timeout only returning an httpConfig customise to your need.

```
RestangularConfigurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {

        httpConfig.url = "http://google.com";
        httpConfig.method = "GET";
        httpConfig.params = "";

        return {
            httpConfig: httpConfig
        };
    });
```

It will be pass on and your service or controller won't know that something change, that's the principle of interceptor, it allow you to change stuff and returning to be use by the next process a bit like a middleware. And so it will be transparent to the one making the call but the call will be made to what you want.

Comment: I read multiple discussions on people trying to abort a restangular request and serve a cached result instead. I want to go a step further and do the request myself. But even aborting is terribly ugly (request still goes out). I was hoping there's a better way.